# Python striping extra characters

Tags: python, string, strip

I'm trying to understand what string.strip() in python is doing:

```
In [35]: t1 = '-MIN-North'

In [36]: t1.strip('-MIN-')
Out[36]: 'orth'

In [37]: t2 = '-MIN-north'

In [38]: t2.strip('-MIN-')
Out[38]: 'north'
```

Why is `t1.strip('-MIN-')` not equal to `'North'` but `t2.strip('-MIN-')` equal to `'north'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strip` is taking out all the *characters* you provide it in the argument.

In your first example, it is stripping out the `N` from `North` because `N` is in `-MIN-`.

In the second, it is not stripping the `n` from `north` because `n` is *not* in `-MIN-`.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting can strip be applied with an exact match? Or would regex be needed here

Comment: A regex would work, alternatively: `t1.replace('-MIN-','')`